# Printing promt before user input

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml, and now I am trying to make a simple REPL.

```
let rec repl () = 
    print_prompt () ;
    let input = Scanf.scanf "%s" (fun x -> x) in
    if input = "" then repl ()
    else print_endline input

let print_prompt () = print_string "> "
```

The problem now i am having is: when program starts, it does not display prompt immediately. It waits for my input and prints prompt along with my input.

What I want is:

```
> "user_input"
"user_input"
```

But i am getting :

```
"user_input"
> "user_input"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you didn't show the `print_promt` implementation, but I can guess, that it uses some buffered io function like `print_string` or `printf`. They print into an intermediate buffer and data will not be displayed unless `flush` is called. You can use `flush` or `flush_all` functions to do this manually. Also you can use a special specificator `%!` in `printf` formats string:

```
 open Printf

 let print_prompt () = printf "> %!"
```

Answer (score 4):

Using readline instead of Scanf :

val read_line : unit -> string

Flush standard output, then read characters from standard input until a newline character is encountered. Return the string of all characters read, without the newline character at the end.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a buffering problem. In your `print_prompt` function, flush the standard output:

```
flush stdout
```